# When asked "Why do you want to switch your job?" whats a good approach?

Tags: job-change

Its a common question and of course very natural for an employer to ask an applicant: "So, you have a job at the moment, then why do you want to change?"

I guess the best I can do is to give a genuine answer: "Want to see a new company, fits better my interests, closer to my living place, see more perspectives, ...".

Or would this be too much about myself, what's the benefit for the company when I work closer to my living place? So would they be happier when hearing

"I think in this position I can deliver more value to the company" or something like that?

Comment: Sort of duplicate except there the OP was approached

Comment: Quite what i wrote in the first part, mostly closer alignment withmy skills and interests, and curiosity for a new place

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your genuine answer. Those are all good reasons to change jobs. Don't try to put a "creative" spin with insincere gibberish. You will get entangled in your own lies when you do that. Unless your genuine reason is "my boss/coworker is an idiot and I fear I will be charged with assault some day if I stay there too long.", don't try to invent artificial stories in the interview.